Is Salesforce Deprecating WITH SECURITY_ENFORCE?
I was recently going through the Enforce User Mode for Database Operations salesforce documentation. In that documentation salesforce recommends to use USER_MODE to enforce FLS instead of WITH SECURITY_ENFORCE.

Salesforce recommends that you enforce Field Level Security (FLS) by
using WITH USER_MODE rather than WITH SECURITY-ENFORCED.

So I am wondering:-

Is salesforce planning to deprecate this in coming future?
If My code is not account for below thing and it is achieving the security with a combination of "with sharing at class level for record sharing + WITH SECURITY_ENFORCE for FLS", should we still plan them to revert as per salesforce recommendation ?




Is salesforce planning to deprecate this in coming future?

At the time of this answer, there's no plan to deprecate WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED. The recommendation comes from the fact that user mode is more functional, as outlined in the documentation.

If My code is not account for below thing and it is achieving the security with a combination of "with sharing at class level for record sharing + WITH SECURITY_ENFORCE for FLS", should we still plan them to revert as per salesforce recommendation ?

Generally speaking, you don't need to worry about upgrading to the new user mode unless you have a need to do so, such as a Security Review that failed because of improper application of recommended security policies. However, new code that you're writing should prefer the new user mode feature, as it is more robust.
